# Python TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)

Tags: python, web-crawler

I am trying the build a crawler, and I want to print all the links on that page
I am using Python 3.5

there is my code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
def crawler(link):
    source_code = requests.get(link)
    source_code_string = str(source_code)
    source_code_soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code_string,'lxml')
    for item in source_code_soup.findAll("a"):
        title = item.string
        print(title)

crawler("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pLHejmLB16o")
```

but I get the error like this

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-9aa10c5a03ef> in <module>()
----> 1 crawler('http://archive.is/DPG9M')

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: have you tried renaming your `crawler` method?

Comment: yes, I changed "crawler" into "cat", but still the same mistake

Answer (score 2):

If you are intentions are to just print the titles of the link, you are making a small mistake, replace the line :

```
source_code_string = str(source_code)
```

use

```
source_code_string = source_code.text
```

Apart from that the code looks fine and is running.
lets call the file web_crawler_v1.py

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
def crawler(link):
    source_code = requests.get(link)
    source_code_string = source_code.text 
    source_code_soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code_string,'lxml')
    for item in source_code_soup.findAll("a"):
        title = item.string
        print(title)


crawler("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pLHejmLB16o")
```

And about that error, you should not be getting that error if you are calling the file properly like this

```
python3 wen_crawler_v1.py
```

Comment: I have another question. I am using Jupyter Notebook, and when I type these code in the notebook RootPython it works. But when I create a new py file (test.py)and put the same code in it and type "import test.py"  then it doesn't work, do you know why ?

Comment: I have tested it and it works, but is the file in the same location where you are calling it from? because that could be a problem if its not.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

`source_code = requests.get(link)`

use:

`source_code = requests.get(link, verify = False)`

You will get a HTTPS warning but the code will execute